# Iterative solver for high order DG methods (3D Laplace problem)

Tags: finite-element, iterative-method, discontinuous-galerkin

I have a 3D Laplace problem on quite a complicated geometry where I am using Discontinuous Galerkin method. My mesh is composed by hexas, hence I am employing classical tensor product basis functions $\mathcal{Q}^p$.

The mesh is not very fine, it is made by $1600$ elements. For every polynomial degree I am solving the same equation $- \Delta u =f$ with the symmetric interior penalty method, in order to perform a convergence test w.r.t the polynomial degree.

Here are the numbers of DoFs per polynomial degree:

- $\mathcal{Q}^1: 12 800$
- $\mathcal{Q}^2: 43 200$
- $\mathcal{Q}^3: 102 400$
- $\mathcal{Q}^4: 200 000 $

As solver I am using conjugate gradient, preconditioned by AMG implementation by Trilinos (with the option high order elements set to true). The absolute tolerance set inside the CG solver is $1e-11$.

Everything goes smoothly in terms of convergence rates until degree $3$ (even if with a lot of CG iterations, see next list), but with $\mathcal{Q}^4$ elements the solver takes simply forever even when I am running in parallel.

Iteration counts:

- $\mathcal{Q}^1: 123$
- $\mathcal{Q}^2: 534$
- $\mathcal{Q}^3: 10869$

I am aware this is a typical problem with high order DG, but the size of the problem is not too large in my opinion, so I wanted to ask if the community is aware of some good alternative matrix-based solver (matrix-free is currently not an option) for such a middle-sized problem.

Comment: Does your system matrix change during simulation? If not, are you able to store the sparse representation?

Comment: I am not sure I follow you @ConvexHull
 What do you mean with "during simulation"? It's a Laplace problem which I solve with different polynomial degrees. There's no time dependency.

Comment: My intention was to ask you if something prevents you to precompute and store the LU-decomposition.

Comment: I guess nothing stops me from doing that, but let me make sure: are you referring to ILU preconditioning? @ConvexHull

Comment: No I mean a direct solver. That's the reason for my first question. Do you have to solve the Laplacian ones or for many different RHSs?

Comment: For every polynomial degree $p$, I am solving $- \Delta u = f$ with symmetric interior penalty with polynomial degree $p$ and a given manufactured $f$. They are all independent problems. I updated the question. I don't think a sparse direct solver could work for larger degrees such as $p=4$. @ConvexHull

Comment: Sparse direct solver would be fine for 200k-by-200k matrices given you have enough RAM. Otherwise I would suggest algebraic multigrid. PETSc, trilinos and hypre have good implementation.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas I have a couple of question about AMG (I am using TrilinosML implementation of AMG)... Are you using it to precondition CG? Isn't AMG bad for high order elements?

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Sure does it work and is most often the right way to go, especially for such a simple PDE. The challenge here is neither the high (and different) polynomial degree, neither the DG method nor a complicated geometry. OP seems to be quite resistent to advise. Let's see if something better pops up.

Comment: @ConvexHull I didn't mean to be resistent to advise, I'm sorry. To be honest, CG + AMG was my first choice and with $p=4$ it was taking forever with (10 MPI ranks), that's why I asked this question. Could you pleas elaborate a bit more on your approach? How would you use the LU decomposition of $A$?

Comment: @FEGirl Maybe this will help: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/42712/36512

Comment: Ah, I see now. That's also what the sparse direct solver by trillions that I am using right now is doing (Amesos_Klu). Indeed, it works for $p=4$.

Comment: However, when the size of $A$ is 345.000 (corresponding to $p=5$), it appears it's  quite slow... would you move to CG+AMG in this case? @ConvexHull

Comment: KLU(2) is, in my opinion, a single threaded reference implementation, it is a decent linear solver but not a good one. Maybe Basker is better but I haven't tried it myself. I would try using MKL Pardiso, SuperLU or MUMPS. If they are also slow (which I don't think they will be), you can try CG+AMG

Comment: @FEGirl I would recommend the approach of Abdullah

Comment: @ConvexHull Direct solvers in 3d for high-order polynomials are going to run out of memory real quick. They are not a good choice.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I appreciate your reply. I think it is common knowledge that there are limits for direct solvers in 3D. I would not recommend the usage for bigger problems. When a mesh hierarchy is available, geometric multigrid is a natural choice, especially for higher polynomial degrees. However, multgrid for small and medium problems such as $\mathcal{Q}_{1,2,3,4}$ seems quite off for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to solve high-order problems efficiently is to use a multigrid method in which the first coarsening steps reduce the polynomial degree by one in each step, followed by (geometric) coarsening of the mesh. In many cases, if you don't have a mesh hierarchy, you can stop the hierarchy when you are at a $Q^1$ element on your mesh and simply apply CG+AMG at that level, for which you have shown that it converges efficiently. Alternatively, you can insert one more level to the hierarchy here where you go from the discontinuous $Q^1$ element to using continuous $Q^1$.

I will say that I think that 123 CG iterations for a $Q^1$ element on just 16,000 cells seems too much to me. I would have expected something in the range of perhaps 20 instead, at least if you used continuous elements. Perhaps the discontinuous ones are more complicated to solve, but I don't have that much experience with DG discretizations.